# ASP.NET Core - 2.1 to 2.2 Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

Visual Studio 2017 15.9.18 on Windows 10

I have an ASP.NET Core Project that I need to update the Target Framework from 2.1 to 2.2
After changing the Target Framework, I cleaned an re-built the project.

I now get a compile error saying that says one of the assemblies in my project uses '**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions**, Version=2.1.1.0 which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0

In my project dependencies I have Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 installed. I was going to update this but in package manager the Update button is disabled, saying "Implicitly referenced by an SDK. To update the package, update the SDK to which it belongs." The versions available show they go up to 2.2.8

Using Nuget Package Manager I installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.1.1.0 and that seemed to work in debug, but after publishing, my site fails to load.

Should I be manually updating the version of **Microsoft.NETCore.App**, or is it fine to just update the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions**?

I added the following to my project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.2.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I also noticed some invalid sections in my publish profile:

[image: PublishProfile]

I also read somewhere that I should add:
**services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);**
but SetCompatibilityVersion does not appear as a method.

Comment: Have you read [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Why are you migrating to .NET Core 2.2? .NET Core 2.2 is EOL. .NET Core 2.1, on the other hand, is on LTS. So I would suggest you to stay on .NET Core 2.1 or upgrade to .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage upgrading from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 2.2 at this time.

Today's date is 1/4/2020 and as of December 23, 2019 .NET Core 2.2 is at the End of Lifecycle (EOL)

If you're going to spend the time migrating your code at this time, you should move to a version of .NET Core that is going to receive patches if there is anything broken or there are any vulnerabilities.

You can see the EOL dates here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core